# Using Memory Monitor on a single process on Instruments on OS X?

Tags: macos, memory, process, instruments, monitor

I'm having some issues with Instruments on OS X. I'm trying to monitor the memory consumption of a single process over time on OS X. I'm using Instruments 4.1 for that, with the "Memory Monitor" instrument.

On the [Official Instruments Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Built-InInstruments/Built-InInstruments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH6-SW32), Apple states that **"This instrument [Memory Monitor] can operate on a single process or on all processes currently running on the system."** However, even when I set the current target to a *specific process*, it seems to monitor *all the processes* on the machine.

Here's a screenshot of my current setup:

[image: Screenshot of Instruments]

Am I doing something wrong? How can I get Instruments to monitor the memory consumption of a single process?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong. In my experience the various Monitor instruments monitor all processes even if you tell them to monitor only one application.

If you want to monitor your application's memory consumption, use the Allocations instrument. The Live Bytes column for the All Allocations category will tell you how much memory your application is using.